# What is the different between react component and function as component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very confused learning react.
For example I have very simple react component

```
export default function Foo(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>some text</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And I want to add a child component:

```
export default function Foo(){

    const Bar  = ()=>{
        return (
            <input placeholder="some input"/>
        )
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <div>some text</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And as much as I know, I can use this component in two ways:

**1. Use as function**

```
return(
        <div>
            <div>some text</div>
            {Bar()}
        </div>
    )
```

**2. use as component:**

```
 return(
        <div>
            <div>some text</div>
            <Bar/>
        </div>
    )
```

What exactly different between these two? I thought it was same, until I faced an issue with input field, that if I use component as `<Bar/>`, **The focus on input field will be lost after I enter first letter**

Demo here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-archimedes-l7bce7?file=/src/App.js

So what is the exact problem here? I code as component all the time, as per my understand `<Bar/>` is same as `Bar()` when it return ***react component***

Am I right or not?

Edit: I found this blog, and it very close to this question and it great too :)
https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l?signin=true

Comment: Good question. I am also looking for very accurate solution.

Comment: The blog anwers to your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To be a `component`, function returning `JSX` should be used as `<Component />` and `not as Component()`.
2. When a functional component is used as `<Component />` it will have a `lifecycle` and can have a `state`.
3. When a function is called `directly as Component()` it will just run and (probably) return something. `No lifecycle, no hooks`, none of the React magic.

**The above 3 statement is the answer to your probem**.

When you call the component as {Child()}, it does not have any lifecycle or hook and when you call as , it has it's own lifecycle and hooks this is why you are facing those problems.

For more read on this topis: [Link](https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your codesand box demo,
form there I think that the reason for losing focus from `input field` is the place where you have used `useState`.

Your can do **two** things here that's:

**Either**

1. Pass the state as props from parent to child component.

**Or**

2. use `useState` inside your child component as the **parent does not require the state value** I prefer the second way.

You can Read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) for more knowledge of where to put the `useState` and when  do you really need to use `useState`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new component you can re-use that in another functional component.Whereas, If you create function then you cannot re-use in another functional component, it will have limited access to that particular functional component only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain why it happen?

Comment: I forked your code. Have a look, it's working even after typing one word.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-einstein-eyc12e

Comment: Thank @Mr.Gandhi, but I really want to know what exactly cause this